# Fixing ceramic tile that have a large ceramic chip off

Tags: ceramic-tile

How do I fix ceramic tile that have a large ceramic chipped off. (the size is around 5 cm width and 3 cm height).

Overall, the whole tile is still intact except that part of the top layer, which is the ceramic material, was chipped off.

Please enlighten me.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want?  Do you want it to look better, the tile to perform better, or just want it flat again?

Answer (score 2):

Patch it with porcelain crack repair. Or for just a color match, and if it's not in a high traffic area, believe it or not I've had a lot of success using crayon: lots of color choices and it's not permanent, so you can try different colors until something works. If you work it into the repair well enough it will stay better than you expect. I did this over a year ago in our living room, it's really hard to see a repair was made there and I haven't had to re-color it.

Comment: You used crayon and then coated it with clear epoxy?

Comment: No just crayon and buffed with a paper towel. Be aware this when's to hide a crack. I don't foresee if working for large chips. Sounds crazy but worked very well for me

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you do not have additional matching tile. Take a small sample of existing tile and head to the nearest drug store I.e walgreens or cvs.
Purchase nail polish that matches the tile color. Nail polish is hard when dry and it covers nicely. I have done this many times for clients and they were very satisfied with the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the chip, you can try super gluing it back on.  Or you can try looking for some craft enamel paint that is a close match to hide the chip.  Otherwise there is no repair method that I know of short of replacing the damaged tile.  And if this is in a high traffic area, this might be your only option.

Comment: Actually, it is not in a high traffic area. It is a wall ceramic tile inside the bathroom.

Comment: My experience is that there is no good repair method for tile other than to replace it.  You often can get replacement tile (even for homes built in the 70's) that is very close match wise.  However, even then the match is not exact and there's a noticeable difference.  Take your pick Notice the Glue job or Notice Tile color variation.  Or maybe it's time for new tile job?

Answer (score 0):

As diceless suggested, if you have the chip, you can probably glue it back in.  If you don't, then your best bet would be to chisel out the entire tile and replace it.  This assumes that you have some extras remaining, or you can find one that will look good as an accent tile there.  It may be difficult matching the grout though.

Answer (score 0):

Try a porcelain repair compound such as this one:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Homax-White-Porcelain-Chip-Fix-2164/203086992

They can be used to repair chips in porcelain/ceramic coated sinks, tubs, etc. a wall or floor tile should be repairable with it as well.

Comment: This is a dead link